# Associating two models with `has_many, through: relationship` without `belongs_to`

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Sushi application. I'm modeling Sushi `Roll`s with several `Ingredient`s, which have `IngredientType`s (the last of which may or may not be irrelevant). I'm trying to link `Ingredient`s to `Roll`s by doing the following:

**Roll model**

```
class Roll < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients, through: :roll_ingredients
end
```

**Ingredient model**

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :ingredient_type
end
```

**Roll_Ingredient model**

```
class Roll_Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :roll
  has_many :ingredients
end
```

where ingredient is something like Salmon, Avocado, Cream Cheese, or Mango.

- What is a table like `roll_ingredients` called?
- Is the `roll_ingredients` table just a reference-column to a roll and several reference-columns to each ingredient?  What happens when I want to add a new ingredient, do I have to update my table description?
- Further down the line, if I want to describe a roll by its ingredient types, how should/would I want to express the following pseudo-code:

  ```
  class Rolls
    has_many :ingredient_types, through: :ingredients, through: :roll_ingredients
  end
  ```

If this is an inefficient way to approach this problem, please let me know a better method or design pattern for such a model.

Comment: Are you trying to build a many-to-many relationship between `Roll` and `Ingredient`?

Comment: Your Ingredient model is invalid.